# ajax calls not being made after doPostBack

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am making the users download a file on an anchor tag click. On its onclick event, i have used __doPostBack to partial post back the page to return the file which is downloadable by the user.

Now the problem i am facing is, that when the file is not found, the page reloads and the ajax calls are not set. So, in short, when the browser is expecting a response after _doPostBack function, and does not get one, it reloads the page but $.ajax methods do not run. What am i missing? Should I do something with the response? or is there any way that the response can be cancelled? Please help.

The anchor tag is, for instance

```
<a onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AnnouncementAttachmentDownload','Ch 7 -Software Design2010.doc')">Ch 7 -Software Design2010.doc</a>
```

The server side code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetPageTitles(ModuleNames.NotSpecified, null, false, true, true, false);
    if (this.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] == "AnnouncementAttachmentDownload")
    {
    string FileName = this.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString();
        string destinationPath = Server.MapPath("~/" + System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AnnouncementAttachmentsPath"]).ToString() + "\\";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(destinationPath + FileName))
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
            Response.TransmitFile(destinationPath + FileName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "NewScript", "alert('The requested file could not be found, please contact portal.production.support');", true);\\DOESNT WORK
        }

    }
}
```

The line in the else part, it just shows the message but the page loads after that too.

Comment: If you are having to manually deal with `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` and manually call `__doPostBack` you should probably reconsider your design.  There are nice AJAX event handler models built-in to ASP.Net that abstracts all these things away.  Also, why not just use a handler, like `Download.ashx` as your link for downloading the files?

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` or `href="#"` in the anchor?
`<a onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AnnouncementAttachmentDownload','Ch 7 -Software Design2010.doc'); return false;">Ch 7 -Software Design2010.doc</a>`

Comment: mellamokb 
I am using a handler for uploading the files, but it is reached with a javascript ajax handler. Dont know how would i reach one directly through my own javascript.

TryingToImprove
__doPostBack doesnt look href or return, it just posts back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the file not being found, i used Responce.Redirect to redirect it to the current page again, before that I stored a bool in a session variable, and on pageload i checked the session variable if it contained some value and then showed the message. Also, i cleared the session too on in the above if expression.